# Cannot connect to remote server while sending mail

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient, mailmessage

I'm using code below to send an email and it just doesn't work and gives an exception:

```
MailDefinition md = new MailDefinition();
md.IsBodyHtml = true;
md.From = EMAIL_FROM;
md.Subject = "لینک تغییر رمز";
MailMessage mm = md.CreateMailMessage(to, null, new System.Web.UI.Control());
string body = link;
mm.Body = body;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Host = EMAIL_SMTP;
smtp.Port = EMAIL_PORT;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(EMAIL_FROM, EMAIL_PASSWORD);
smtp.Send(mm);
```

where sender username & password are checked and correct, port is 25 and smtp is mail.kawp.co.ir, on send function it throws an exception with the below error message

```
{"Unable to connect to the remote server"}
{"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xxx.xx.xx:25"}
```

I'm using the same method and function for my other domains which are hosted on the same server and they are working fine. What possibly could be causing the problem here?

**p.s**: I also can't handshake with the mail.kawp.co.ir 25 via telnet

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Changing port 25 to 587 fixed my problem because my isp is blocking port 25 to prevent spamming.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot perform the handshake with Telnet, then you're not going to get it to connect programmatically.  From what it sounds like, the server isn't configured to accept SMTP messages.  You'll need to get that enabled before you can get your code to work.

Comment: Well I've fixed it today by changing the port 25 to 587 because my isp has blocked port 25 to prevent spamming(I don't know but that sounds stupid to me) so basically I couldn't get to handshake with telnet while I was doing it locally.

Comment: If you're running McAfee Antivirus, that may have been the cause.  They have a special check in their to prevent spamming.